# How to make first image larger in Gridlayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

To be precise I want to achieve this.
[image]

I am using recyclerview with GridLayoutManager. I also have made first item large using the following code

```
        lLayout.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int i) {
            if (i==0) return 2;
            else return 1;
        }
    });
```

Everything works fine except one: The item at position 1 (ie next item from large image) is elongated vertically to match the height of large item. From row 3 all images are as shown in the image.

How can I get rid of this ?

**Edit: After some analysis**

So the problem seems to be that the large image is taking two spans horizontally but single span vertically and since I have forced my ImageView to be square, it looks like it has also taken two rows where as in fact it is a single row. Due to this reason the second image seems elongated.

So now my question is, how to make grid item take two spans vertically and two spans horizontally ?

Comment: Have you found solution for this?

Comment: [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) is the closest I have found.

Comment: Hi @rockfight, I am still looking for a proper solution. Did you find anything you can share? I would be very grateful

Comment: Hi @MehdiSatei , this was a very old thread and I have almost completely forgot what I did on this. The project is also retired. Also I have shifted completely to React Native for mobile development. So I am unable to help.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use **StaggeredGridLayoutManager** instead of **GridLayoutManager**. [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) supports horizontal & vertical layout as well as an ability to layout children in reverse. 
*onBindViewHolder* method of adapter you can set span according to position of your item using this code

```
final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();    
if (position == 0) {
                StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams sglp = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) lp;
                sglp.setFullSpan(true);
                holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(sglp);
            }
```

find the example http://enoent.fr/blog/2015/01/18/recyclerview-basics/... hope it will help you

Comment: The link is very useful for understanding `RecyclerView`.. Thank you

Comment: Well first of all GridLayoutManager also supports  horizontal & vertical layout as well as ability to layout children in reverse. Your code will make the view span whole width due to setFullSpan(true). What I want is make first image span double the size of other items, i.e two span vertically and two horizontally. I also recommend the link to understand the recyclerview, its very helpful.

Comment: @rockfight It is quite helpful to share with other developers, if you found the right way

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in GridViewAdapter class

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Integer> imageArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private int type;

public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> imageArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.imageArrayList = imageArrayList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return imageArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        type = getItemViewType(position);
        if(type==0) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.big_layout,parent,false);
        }else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.small_layout, parent, false);
        }
        viewHolder.imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(imageArrayList.get(position)));
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return super.getViewTypeCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position==0) {
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}

    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work since I am using RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager instead of GridView.